# Create User (Bash Script) through Php form

Tags: php, mysql, bash

Can anyone help me on this simple thing? I have a php registration form that communicates directly with MySQL database and adds users when someone fulfils the form. The problem starts when I want to also create a home directory for each user (with a bash script) that makes this registration.

What I've done: I created a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo useradd -m /home/$1
```

Whatever parameter I made on this simple script until now didn't work in order to create the user's home directory.

Comment: what kind of 'users' are they who get a home directory on the server?

Comment: Is apache (or `www-data`) a sudoer?

Comment: I hope your users can't input names like `user -g0` or `user -Gsudo` or you'll have surprises! Anyway, my message is: Use More Quotes!

Comment: to accomplish that, you'll probably also need something like `suexec` on your apache server

Answer (score 1):

**Problems:**

1. **Explicit home directory:** Your command line syntax is wrong.  Try the following instead:

   `sudo useradd -m username`

   or

   `sudo useradd -d /home/username -m username`
2. **Is PHP a sudoer?** Only certain accounts are able to execute sudo.  Check that the account PHP runs under is listed in the sudoers file.  You can usually easily the file with

   `visudo`
3. **Is PHP `chroot`-ed?** If so, you may not be able to create new linux user accounts from scripts with any reasonable code.

**A working test**

The following worked for me under Debian (without sudo).

*newuser.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
useradd -d /home/$1 -m $1
```

*newuser.php*

```
<?php
  exec('/bin/bash /var/www-scripts/newuser.sh joe');
?>
```

*test invocation:* `php newuser.php`

If you can perform the same tests (but add sudo as needed), then the only reason it would not work when invoked by your web server is a security problem.  That could either be a chroot environment, or lacking sudoer privilege.

**Additional resources**

You can see how other people have solved this problem by reviewing the following:

1. http://www.weberdev.com/get_example.php3?ExampleID=3766
2. http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/176031-solved-crafting-php-script-create-unix-user.html

Comment: no nothing again :(
I also used the sudo visudo command 

www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/fredehosting/adduser.sh

Comment: @misthe Have you confirmed that PHP runs under www-data? Sometimes PHP is configured to run under a different account for security reasons -- particularly if serving scripts from multiple users.

Comment: well after looking it more carefully i think that the request might not works correct from my php. form, that's why the bash script not executed  !!!

Comment: @misthe Ok, it sounds like the problem is solved. Hopefully I was at least helpful with the command line stuff. :-)

Comment: to be honest No i type the command from my PhP like this and can create the User. I also try it the shell_exec the same problem ..    exec(" /bin/bash /var/www/fredhosting/adduser.sh $username");

Comment: @misthe It might be that your PHP is being run in a chrooted environment.  See my edited answer which has a lot more detail, and links you will find directly relevant.